# Question regarding extremities in Boxplots.

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, percentile

[image: Boxplot image]

The minimum is mentioned as Q1-1.5*IQR. Q1 is 25th percentile, and 1.5*IQR is 75%. So how does the minimum work when Q1-1.5*IQR should be (-25th) percentile.

Comment: $50\%$ of the data is concentrated in the pink box with its width being the marked IQR.  It it that width (not the $50\%$) which is multiplied by $1.5$.  The data is not uniformly distributed: in this case it seems to be concentrated towards the middle

Comment: Yes this happens to be an ideal example of a boxplot. So basically what you are saying is that if the distribution of the data is more concentrated the IQR decreases in length but remains the same in percentage, and that length is used to mark minimum and maximum.

Comment: The IQR gives the ends of the box.  $1.5\, IQR$ on top of that gives the extremes of the whiskers if the data stretches that far. Anything further away is shown as a dot

Comment: Conventions for making and interpreting boxplots may differ slightly from one textbook or computer program to another. However, it seems that you are confusing the lower and upper 'fences' Q1 - 1.5 IQR and Q3 + 1.5 IQR on the one hand with the minimum and maximum on the other. Outside the **fences** one usually pots individual points ("outliers"). By contrast out beyond the **extremes** (min and max), there are no points to plot.